# Splitting a massive table into 10+ 1 to 1 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've come across a table that has about 200 columns. About 150 of these can be grouped into 5-10 tables that make real world "sense", and seeing as most of these entries are never used I figured it save a lot of null pointers and reduce the size of the database drastically if I did this.

e.g. lets say the current main table has these entries:

```
Id | Person |  DOB  | Address   | FaveColour | LeastFaveColour | MoreColourOpinions
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    Jim      1992    Here        null         null              null
2    Bob      1991    There       Brown        Orange            I like purple
3    Bill     1990    Everywhere  null         null              null
```

So here you might have guessed that I would split the columns relating to colour into a separate table.

```
Id | Person |  DOB  | Address 
-----------------------------
1    Jim      1992    Here      
2    Bob      1991    There
3    Bill     1990    Everywhere


PersonId | FaveColour | LeastFaveColour | MoreColourOpinions
------------------------------------------------------------
2          Brown        Orange            I like purple
```

Now, I know that it's totally fine to have 1-1 tables, but my question relates to speed - what's going to be the difference between querying the original gargantuan table vs. querying all the separate tables `left joined` together?

Let's say the table has half a million rows and I want to query on one thing from EVERY group, e.g.

```
Select * from Person p
left join ColourOpinions co on p.Id = co.PersonId
-- add another ten+ left joins
where co.FaveColour = 'Brown'
-- and another filter, one for each of the ten+ joins
```

I *assume* that querying the original table will be faster, because there's no joins to be made, and with all those joins I'm basically recreating the entire original table before querying it... but how much slower will it be then? Is it really a good idea to split this table up?

I'm thinking **yes** because querying the speed of querying smaller tables and joins separately, as well as the database size difference, will totally offset any occasion where we need to recreate the entire original table and query that?! I'm just not sure of the drawbacks to breaking down such a large table.

Comment: Q: You're familiar with [database normal forms](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/normal-forms-in-dbms/), right?  There's nothing inherently wrong with a table having 200 (or more!) columns.

Comment: Queries against smaller tables (especially many of them) aren't quicker Inherently, it's all about the Indexing. If you have the right indexes, and are limiting the final data set (columns as well as rows) then the query will be as "fast".

Comment: "Let's say the table has half a million rows" - that is TINY. Talk a billion and you are not small. Talk 10 billion and you start talking. Modern computers handle half a million rows without even looking at you.

Comment: Hmm so let's say in theory 500 billion rows. What's the speed difference between 1) querying table with 50 columns. 2) querying table with 200 columns. 3) querying four 1-1 tables, left joined, totalling 200 columns (assuming all columns except Id columns are varchar(50))

Answer (score 2):

> seeing as most of these entries are never used I figured it save a lot of null pointers and reduce the size of the database drastically if I did this

Probably won't help much.  If you want to reduce the size, compress the table, or turn it into a [Clustered Columnstore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-ver15), or use [Sparse Columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-sparse-columns?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 1):

It depends...

If say 99% of the time you only want to query the person's name, you should definitely separate the name column or normalizing. In general some degrees of normalization is good.
Because it could save disk space and memory by reducing redundant data.

However if you find yourself joining your tables all the time and performance is top priority for you. You can make your query faster by de-normalizing. Provided all the necessary index are there and you have enough memory and disk space on your server. As joins could slow down the query.

It is a trade off between space and time IMO (nothing to do with quantum mechanics :-)).

Also if all you worried about is unnecessary null fields in your table. They do not actually take much disk space if at all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, on further inspection these values that SHOULD be null have been default populated with text e.g. "Nothing" or "no value"... I don't know WHY it's been done like that but I can probably fix a few speed and space issues by making them true NULL

Answer (score 0):

This very much depends on the queries that you are writing.

If your queries are returning only a single person, then the one-table structure requires and index lookup and a single read from a data page.

The `join` queries require looking up rows in each table.  Although these would probably use primary key indexes, there would be additional work.

If your queries are scanning the entire table, then the answer is much more "it depends".  `NULL` values in tables usually occupy some space.  So, the question is whether this additional space outweighs the reading of multiple table.

If most columns are very sparse, then it is quite possible that the multi-table approach would be better.  If they are all filled in, then the multi-table approach would occupy more space (because of the keys linking the tables) and more I/O.

What I would say is that you may be looking at pre-mature optimization.   You should store the data in the most natural format for the data model, and work on optimizing the data model for the use-cases that are really needed rather than focusing on generic "which is better" questions.